Utils.dart error - mediaQuery().boldText - Flutter
I am developing an mobile app in flutter. It was running fine, but this error message started to show-up when I tried to run the app again.
I have the pics of the error and the utils.dart and public.yaml files, which I already updated.
Please, can you help with it ?
The error message public.yaml filethe utils.dart file
I updated my pubspec.yaml, checked the code for any mediaQuery().boldText..., and utilized different flutter versions.
